# Why my Scala method type resolves to Buffer instead of List?

Tags: scala

For the method definition below, when I explicitly set return type to `List[String]`, the compiler complains because it expects (mutable) `Buffer[String]`. **Why is that?** Every possible case inside `flatMap` returns `List[String]`. Where and why is the List -> Buffer conversion happening?

```
private def getHitTerms(q: Query, searcher: IndexSearcher, docId: Int): List[String] = {

    val bq = q.asInstanceOf[BooleanQuery]

    bq.clauses().asScala.flatMap(c => {
      val q = c.getQuery()
      if (q.isInstanceOf[BooleanQuery]) {
        getHitTerms(q, searcher, docId)
      } else if (searcher.explain(q, docId).isMatch()) {
        if (q.isInstanceOf[TermQuery]) {
          List(c.getQuery().asInstanceOf[TermQuery].getTerm().text())
        } else if (q.isInstanceOf[PhraseQuery]) {
            List(c.getQuery().asInstanceOf[PhraseQuery].getTerms().map(_.text()).mkString(" "))
        } else List.empty[String]
      } else List.empty[String]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is `asScala`. This will convert a Java collection into a buffer usually. You should add `.toList` after it, so `bq.clauses().asScala.toList.flatMap(c => {...`

Comment: I missed it. Thank you!